# Multiple if statements with locks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple if statements like this:

```
if (variable == something && lock01 == false)
{
  do your thing
  lock01=false; lock02=true; lock03=true; ....
}
else
{
  lock01=true; lock02=false; lock03=true;
}
```

This locks all other if statements so only one is active at a time. The problem with this is if I add more if statements, I have to add more locks by hand. It also only works from top to bottom one after another. Is there a better way to do this? If it's easier in Jquery, JQ code is also ok.

edit: I forgot to write that I loop through the if statements and only one can be unlocked at a time.

Comment: I don't understand, can't you just use a var holding the number of the lock currently active?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this construct? I'm thinking you might want a state machine

Comment: @Margaret I don't quiet get it can you make an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is to use switch statements instead of "n" if/else statements.

So you code will looks like:

```
switch(variable) {
    case 1:
        do your things here;
        break;
    case 2:
        do something else;
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        when variable is 3 or 4 do the same code
        break;
    default:
        do something else;
        lock = false;
}
```

and so on.
Switch statements works with strings or numbers (as far as I know), just make sure to use quote with strings (e.g.: case 'something').

If you don't want to use switch statements, then use else/if:

```
if(variable == something) {
    do something;
}
else if(variable == something_else) {
    do something_else;
}
else {
    lock = false
}
```

This way only the first matched "if" will be executed.

Comment: Sry forgot to write that I loop trough the if statements. How would I loop through the switch?

Comment: Since the switch can't seem to handle complex cases, only integers I don't think this will work.

Comment: Switch can be used with numbers and strings (see the note below the code), but not object, in this case you could use if/else, or follow what @Hatchet said. You can obviously wrap the switch and/or the if/else statements in a loop: `while(true){switch(var) ... }`

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use a variable that identifies which lock is unlocked:

```
unlocked = "lock01";
// or
unlocked = 1;
```

Then your code could look something like this:

```
if (variable == something && unlocked === 1) {
    // do your thing
} else {
    unlocked = 2;
}
```

Comment: sry forgot to write that I loop trough the if statements and only one can be unlocked at a time. This wouldn't work with the loop I think.